# Password recover MVC 5: UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync not available in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, forgot-password

I was  trying to implement the passsword reset token using Rick Anderson's example here http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

When I tried the code for Forgot Password controller in my own application, I do not get an option to select UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync. Has anyone encountered this? I am using MVC 5. Is this possibly a Visual Studio version/update issue? I am using VS 2013 (version 12.0.21005.1 REL).

Thanks,

Sanjeev

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
            return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
        }

        var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", 
        new { UserId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
        await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Reset Password", 
        "Please reset your password by clicking here: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");        
        return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was I had to install Visual Studio Update 2. Now the GeneratePasswordResetToken options appears under UserManager.